# How can i make looping on php like this

Tags: php

The code should be like this

```
01
002
0003
00004
000005
6000000
70000000
800000000
9000000000
10000000000
```

**This my code**

```
for ( $i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++ ){
        echo "<br>";
        for ( $j = 1; $j <= $i; $j++ ){
            for( $k = 1; $k >= $j; $k-- ){
                echo $i;
            }
            if( $i >= $k ) {
                echo "0";
            }
        }
        if ($i >= 6) {
            echo "0";
        }else {
            echo $i;

        }
    }
```

I cant make like the result, can you help me thanks.. no error but weird result

Comment: Share what you have tried ?

Comment: What's stopping you from mirroring after 5? Show what you tried.

Comment: Icant looping like this :(

Comment: wheres the codes?

Comment: I Added new condition : http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a8c78a35d171ec8e818e061e6725fb198d59d44d

Comment: indeed true, but unfortunately the number 0 behind it still exists .. should be parallel ... as in the example

Comment: @Hayukii_: you mean at last for `10` ? what will next for `11` or `12` ?

Comment: Another way with same result as above : http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ed221862ccb739e6df0997c584c07cb585f2c0e8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this (without using any in-build functions):

```
for ( $i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++ ){
    if($i<=5){
        for ( $j = 1; $j <= $i; $j++ ){
            echo "0";
        }
        echo $i;
    }
    if($i>5){
        echo $i;
        for ( $j = 1; $j <= $i; $j++ ){
            echo "0";
        }
    }
    echo "<br>";
}
```

The output will be :

```
01
002
0003
00004
000005
6000000
70000000
800000000
9000000000
100000000000
```

You can test this code in [here](https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ed221862ccb739e6df0997c584c07cb585f2c0e8)

Comment: Thats right, but 0 at number 10 is still more than result

Comment: thank you, your code is correct .. only I had to add 1 more condition ... but that's okay ... thank you very much

Comment: ```for ( $i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++ ){
    if($i<=5){
        for ( $j = 1; $j <= $i; $j++ ){
            echo "0";
        }
        echo $i;
    }
    if($i>5){
        echo $i;
        for ( $k = 1; $k<= $i; $k++ ){ if($k !=10){
            echo "0";}
        }
    }
    echo "<br>";
}```

Answer (score 0):

There is a string function in php called str_pad(). This method will pad a string to a new length of specified characters.

The below link will help to give a detailed explanation on the above string function
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php

The above code can be written as :

```
<?php
for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++){
  $length = $i+1;
  $direction = ($i <= 5) ? STR_PAD_LEFT : STR_PAD_RIGHT;

  echo str_pad($i,$length,"0", $direction);

  echo "<br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: I think he is trying to solve his school assignment, where `no in built` function used.